# What is the nicest bijection $\textbf{R}^p \to \textbf{R}^q$ that you know?

Tags: set-theory, big-list, visualization

It is well-known that bijection between $\textbf{R}^p$ and $\textbf{R}$ exist (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243590/bijection-from-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-rn#), though many other examples exist).

The problem with all these examples of bijections is that typically the mapping does not have any structure (obviously, it cannot be continuous); and most examples do not even make an attempt at providing an $f$ that has some structure.

My question is: What bijections $f:\textbf{R}^p \to \textbf{R}^q$, where you are allowed to specify natural numbers $p\neq q$, do you know that are "nice"?
"Nice" can mean that some basic geometric property is preserved, it can mean that $f$ is interpretable in some way, or it can mean that it is in some other way appealing.

Comment: Do you have any examples to get things started?  Also, since this is inherently a [tag:big-list] question, you might want to flag it for moderator attention to be made Community Wiki.

Comment: @LSpice No "nice" example to get started, unfortunately. It is not too trivial to come up with these, if they really should be bijections (and not just surjections).

Comment: A natural assumption is to require $f$ and $f^{-1}$ to be Borel and this is indeed possible. The classical one would be the "split digits" trick. There's a minor issue that it's not exactly bijective but the correction is only on a countable set.

Comment: @YCor Care to make a short write-up of this and make a start on what will (hopefully) become a community wiki? :)

Comment: You can make $f$ $\mathbb Q$-linear.

Comment: A bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ can be (amost) constructed by interlacing the binary expansions.  (Mentioned by @YCor )  But to get an actual bijection you have to make picky adjustments to account for reals with two different binary expansions.  Altermatively, you could follow logicians and use the term "reals" for ${\mathbb N}^{\mathbb N}$ and then get easy bijections.  See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/65002/454

Comment: However, I don't think $f$ can be made both $\mathbf{Q}$-linear and Borel.

Comment: @YCor Right. A $\mathbb Q$-linear bijection can't even be measurable. Or such that preimages of Borel sets have the property of Baire.

Comment: I suppose one can use "split digits" to go from ${\bf R}^p$ to ${\bf R}^q$ by way of $\bf R$.

Comment: Related to [Gerald Edgar's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454819/what-is-the-nicest-bijection-textbfrp-to-textbfrq-that-you-know#comment1177342_454819): [Simple bijection between reals and sets of natural numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/56633)

Comment: The "split digits" approach that has been mentioned widely isn't really geometric in any ways though. I'm wondering if there do not exist any bijections that have a more visual flavour?

Comment: @user7088941 What do you mean by a visual flavor? Sure the fact that it can't be continuous is already a strong indication that we shouldn't expect any "geometric structure" to be preservable? Maybe if you specify more carefully what you want to be preserved, one will be able to prove a negative result, namely that what you want to be preserved cannot be preserved.

Comment: @TimothyChow You're right. Here's one conjecture: While such a bijection $f$ cannot be globally continuous, there exist subsets with property $\mathfrak{P}$ in $\mathbb{R}^q$ on which it is continuous (where $\mathfrak{P}$ is a property such as being simply connected, or being compact). Would that be true?

Comment: @user7088941 I think you need to be more specific. For example, it's true if the property is "having the discrete topology" but that's presumably not what you mean.